# Когда соединение закрывается HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

Я вот немного не понял стадию закрытия соединения с сервером.

Отсылаю запрос заголовков:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RequestHeaders(Uri requestUri, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri))
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resultMessage =
            await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token);

        return resultMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Соединение будет закрыто при возврате сообщения, или когда будет прочитан запрос, если учитывать ответ с `Connection: Keep-Alive`?

А ответ:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2019 14:21:59 GMT
  ETag: "1254b034-58710390c8f53"
  Server: Apache
  Content-Length: 307540020
  Content-Type: video/mp4
  Last-Modified: Sun, 21 Apr 2019 20:30:29 GMT
}
```

Comment: Интересует как это работает или как лучше поступить?

Comment: Интересует как работает.